# Why is my flask website not updating my spending tracker until after I re-run the program?

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am making a spending tracker in flask. I wanted to add a scrollable chart with all the spending information that is in my SQLite database, but the chart is not updating with the new spendings until after I re-run the site. [image]

Code from the app.py file:
[image]

Code from the html file:

```
 <tbody>
{% for spending in all_spending %}
  <tr><td>{{ spending.spending_type }}</td><td>{{ spending.spending_amount }}</td><td>{{spending.date_time}}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: FYI, your downvotes are probably because of screenshotted code rather than text code for the app.py code.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't rerun your query after posting.  You POST and query  Spending, go through the POST (`form.validate_on_submit()`) code but then return the `all_spending` object you got before the POST.  When you reload the site you do a new query and get everything.

Most POST actions are followed by a redirect so you could add a line after `db.session.commit`

```
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect('/update')  # new line
return render_template...
```